# When I run a program it runs for a microsecond and then closes, without any input on my behalf

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to run a simulation on the Monte Carlo problem. Whenever I try to run my version of the program (meant for up to 100/101 steps) it runs for a split second and then it closes. I can't even add any input whatsoever.

I've tried anything I can think of, including modifying the code of my 50 steps program (which is working accordingly and is exactly the same as my 101 steps program) to try and run it, but the issue remains.

The code as it follows should start by asking the size of the overall net (which should be 50) and, later on the amount of drunkards used (I tipically use 10,000 drunks). The output should be the position of each drunkard, the standard deviation of the amount of drunkards in each position, and an external output with the mount of drunkards per position.

```
implicit none

integer x, y, T, L, N, B, PL, PV, E, DP1
real *8 S(101, 101)
real *8 r
double precision M
real *8 U
real *8 Pit
real *8 Pitotal
real *8 DP2
real *8 DPF
real *8 PVT
real *8 PLT

read(*,*) L !Tamanho da rede
!read(*,*) U !Quantidade de passos
read(*,*) B !Quantidade de bêbados
!Zerar os vetores

!WRITE(*,*) PV, PL
do x = 1, L
  do y = 1, L
    S(x, y) = 0
    !WRITE(*,*) x, y, S(x, y)
  enddo
enddo
 
!Simular Caminhar e Escrever na Matriz
do T = 1, B
  PV = (L/2)+1
  PL = (L/2)+1
  !Determinar a quantidade de passos dados até 101
  !!! THIS IS WHERE BOTH THE 50 STEPS CODE AND THE 101 STEPS CODE DIFFER THIS ONE'S SUPPOSED TO MULTIPLY THE RANDOM NUMBER IN ORDER TO GET A NUMBER OF STEPS THAT DOESN'T EXCEED 101,. WHILE THE OTHER JUST RANDOMLY ASSIGNS 50 OR 51 STEPS.
  call random_number(U)
  U = U * 101 + 1
  !Simular Caminhar
  do N = 1, int(U)
    call random_seed()  !Gerar a seed aleatória
    call random_number(r)
    if (r < 0.5) then
      PV = PV-1
    else
      PV = PV+1
      !WRITE(*,*) PV, PL
    endif
    
    !Junção de contorno para determinar o ponto final mesmo se estourar a rede
    if (PV > L) then
      !PV = 1
      PV = mod(PV,L)
    elseif (PV < 1) then
      !PV = L
      PV = L - mod(PV,L)
    else
    endif
     
    call random_seed()
    call random_number(r)
    if (r < 0.5) then
      PL = PL-1
    else
      PL = PL+1
    endif
    
    !WRITE(*,*) PV, PL
    !Junção de contorno para determinar o ponto final mesmo se estourar a rede
    if (PL > L) then
      !PL = 1
      PL = mod(PV,L) 
    elseif (PL < 1) then
      !PL = L
      PL = L - mod(PV,L)
    else
    endif
  enddo

  WRITE(*,*) PV, PL
  PVT = PV
  PLT = PL
  !Escrever na matriz
  S(PV,PL) = S(PV,PL) + 1
  !Calcular a distância total relativa ao ponto inicial (pitágoras)
  Pit = sqrt((PVT*PVT)+(PLT*PLT))
  Pitotal = Pitotal + Pit
enddo

WRITE(*,*) Pitotal
!Calcular a distância média
M = Pitotal/B
WRITE(*,*) M
!Calcular o Desvio Padrão
do DP1 = 1,B !Somatório
  E = E + ((Pitotal-M) * (Pitotal-M))
enddo
!Dividir o somatório por B * (B-1)
DP2 = E / (B * (B-1))
!Extrair a raíz da divisão
DPF = sqrt(DP2)
WRITE(*,*) E, DP2, DPF
 
!Escrever os resultados
do x = 1, L
  do y = 1, L
    S(x,y) = S(x,y)/B
    WRITE(10,*) x, y, S(x,y)
  enddo
enddo
```

The culprit seems to be the number of steps desired, not even using the same method used in the 50/51 steps program seems to solve it (even though it would be incorrect given the fact that this program should generate steps up to 100/101, not just 100/101 steps). Any ideas on how I can solve this?

p.s. I'm using Visual Studio Code to compile the program and trying to run it on cmd, I already tried to use VSC to run it, but the issue persists.

Comment: I know almost nothing about Fortran, but when I run your code as-is at  https://onlinegdb.com/e8-oYVzc6 it waits for input.  Your question should specify the input required to reproduce the problem, and the expected and actual output.

Comment: Thanks for the info, in my tests, it never got to the input phase, it only starts and ends within a split second. Maybe the reason why it's running is because it contains the sub-routine for 50/51 steps. I'll make it clearer in my question and try to run it at this web site.

Comment: You should still specify the required input.  If the specific error only happens on your platform, perhaps you should also specify that platform and compiler too.  I suggest that you delete the irrelevant code rather then comment it put - Fortran is hard enough to read as it is.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'll do that.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is a text editor, not a compiler. Tell us the version of your compiler and your compiler flags. Try to compile the program on the command line.

Comment: You are not making this particularly easy - there are no prompts for the input. I had to Google translate the comments to figure out where/when to enter the values.

Comment: Runs for me with gfortran-9 on linux. You get NaNs, but one issue at a time. You are putting numbers in, aren't you? What happens if you add prompts for the input as @Clifford suggests?

Comment: Your issue might not be related to your code, but to you compile-and-run workflow. What happens if you try to compile and run a simple "hello world" program?